# How can I use .net API to see if a windows user has access to an SSRS Report?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, report

I am writing a .NET application to host enterprise reports and I need a means to determine if a user, based on their Windows Username, can access the report. The administration of the reports is not my issue. Because there are so many reports I wish to use code to see if the user can access that and hide it's link if they cannot.

Thanks and much appreciation in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use Policy property in ReportService2010 webservice:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.policy.aspx

It would require you to either add service reference to your c# app or create a proxy class which would be used to communicate with the report server.

Comment: Will try this solution. Suggested by my DBA as well. Thanks. Will let you know.